# CSS Pseudo-elements :before & :after work differently in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element

I have a very specific problem as I am trying to create a navigation that has angles using purely CSS without images or javascript. I have figured it out so that it works perfectly but the problem I am coming across is that IE 9 and Chrome look different. I can get both to work by changing the margins of the pseudo elements but I would prefer a single solution to work in both. If anyone can figure out why the margins are different and give me a single CSS solution to work in both browsers that would be great. Otherwise I will have to add a seperate class for IE and force it to work using a seperate CSS entry.

Here is the jsfiddle to work with [arrow-nav](http://jsfiddle.net/rrg3/jSdWR/)

Here is the HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" >Some Navigation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">More navigation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another Nav</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Nav</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">A Test Navigation</a></li>
</ul>
```

The CSS

```css
ul {
    float:right;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width: 300px;
}
ul li a {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
}
ul li{
    float:left;
    width: 300px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-indent:10%;
    background: grey;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
ul li:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-1px;
    border-top: 26px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 26px solid transparent;
    border-right: 21px solid black;
    margin-left:-22px;
}
ul li:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid grey;
    margin-left:-320px;
}
```

Comment: Have you used a CSS-reset stylesheet to reduce/remove the cross-browser defaults?

Comment: I can't get it to work in IE7 or 8 nor in mozilla browsers. That a huge chunk of users! Is this for something internal? And if so, are there any standard-install modules/plugins on the users machines? Just asking in case this is for a company internal site which very often have altered browsers.

Comment: `:before` and `:after` work in IE8 (but not IE7) – http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent. See my answer below for a solution that will work in IE8+

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fix this by using absolute positioning on the pseudo elements. To make this work correctly, set the position of `ul li` to relative (which will cause elements positioned absolutely within it to be relative to the li). Then, update the position of the pseudo elements to use `left` instead of `margin-left`:

```
ul li{
    position: relative; // Add this.
    float:left;
    width: 300px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-indent:10%;
    background: grey;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
ul li:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-1px;
    border-top: 26px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 26px solid transparent;
    border-right: 21px solid black;
    left:-22px; // Update from margin-left to left
}
ul li:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid grey;
    left:-20px; // Update from margin-left to left
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/jSdWR/5/

Comment: It is strange that I have worked with CSS for a very long time and never realized that giving a parent element position relative allowed the absolute positioning of the child element to work with the parent instead of the document. I always avoided absolute positioning because of it only working with the document. This is exactly what I was looking for and simple to update my current code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the position for the elements (for example `top` and `left` values). And for some reason, which I don't fully understand - to add `position: relative` to the `li` (not the `ul`):

http://jsfiddle.net/jSdWR/4/

Comment: Adding `position: relative` to the `li` creates a new positioning context, where elements positioned absolutely within the element will be relative to the parent element (instead of the document, for instance).

Comment: I'm aware of that. :) What makes me wonder is are the `:before` and `:after` elements considered children of the `li` in this case.

Comment: Yes, `:before` and `:after` are considered children of the element they're attached to.  It becomes obvious when you apply a border around it:  http://tinker.io/98f9b