# ::after not working in <option> tag in IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am trying to add a pseudo element (*) for all the required fields in a multi select box. Currently, I am using a class selector in my CSS and applying the style.

The pseudo element is rendered properly in all other browsers except IE 11. Can someone please guide me how to achieve this in IE11.

```css
.requiredField::after {
  content: '*';
  color: green;
  !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<select id="selectedDisplayCols" style="width: 100%;" multiple="">
  <option value="CPP">C++</option>
  <option class="requiredField" value="C">C</option>
  <option class="requiredField" value="Java">Java</option>
</select>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339854/after-before-issues-in-internet-explorer-11

Comment: I'm not somewhere I can check but I think your !important needs to be moved behind 'green'. It can't be a standalone property

Comment: @Gendarme : Thank you. I referred the above example before posting this question. It works with li but not with selects. I am not sure if it is a select box related issue. How IE renders the select?

Comment: @Rob : I have edited the code snippet, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: What happens if you change `::after` to `:after`?

Comment: @AMACB : I tried that, same results.

Comment: Maybe this previous question will help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174233/css-pseudo-elements-before-after-work-differently-in-internet-explorer

Comment: @Maulzal : Somehow, its not working for the <select> fields

Comment: Same results with Microsoft edge..Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `<option>` tags are only able to customize a little, and not in all browsers, IE & Edge doesn't allows you to customize all properties, included pseudo elements like after and before. It works in `<select>` tag, but not in the child options

Comment: More of a question out of curiosity, but why would a select option ever be required?  Can you avoid the issue by instead indicating that these options are added automatically and remove them from the options list?  I would consider it a bad user experience to be required to hunt down all these required options in a multi-select.

Comment: @Joseph Marikle: It wouldn't. It's an oxymoron. An option is by definition not required ;)

Comment: as @BoltClock said, it's an **optional** choice. It's weird to see an option to be required. I think you must to change your logic.